# How to add Breadcrumbs everywhere on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

[image]

Like you can see in the picture, I want to move the breadcrumb from header to the page content.
I tried to insert the code of Yoast SEO into different part of my theme but I didn't succeed. I wanted to put it in `page.php` or `single.php` but it didn't work; it only work in `header.php`. Can someone help me please?

Comment: add here what code you used

Comment: i have the yoast seo plugin instaled so i used this code:
 <?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('
<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
');
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Use `Breadcrumb NavXT` WordPress Plugin For BreadCrumb

Comment: did you put shortcode for it? did you get any error?

Comment: yes i put it and still dont work and not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yoast seo plugin, so using this plugin you can easily get breadcrmb using following code.

```
<?php
 if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
 }
 else{
  echo 'Failed';
 }
```

?>

Comment: yes i used this code : <?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('
<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
');
}
?>